# How to transfer program state, like a window position, to the next run?

Tags: rust

What would be the proper way to store tiny bit of data to reuse?

I am thinking about creating `options.json` file. Any instruments for it?
Another options?

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit bored, so here is the solution you were looking for. It attempts to save an `options.json` file in the same directory as the executable.

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use std::env::current_exe;
use std::io::{self, BufReader, BufWriter, Error, ErrorKind};
use std::fs::File;

pub fn save_data_for_next<D: Serialize>(data: &D) -> io::Result<()> {
    let options_path = current_exe()?.parent().unwrap().join("options.json");
    let writer = BufWriter::new(File::create(options_path)?);
    serde_json::to_writer(writer, data).map_err(|e| Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))
}


pub fn load_previous_data<D: DeserializeOwned>() -> io::Result<Option<D>> {
    let options_path = current_exe()?.parent().unwrap().join("options.json");
    
    if !options_path.is_file() {
        return Ok(None)
    } 
    
    let reader = BufReader::new(File::open(options_path)?);
    match serde_json::from_reader(reader) {
        Ok(v) => Ok(Some(v)),
        Err(e) => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do to use it is to derive `Serialize` and `Deserialize` on some type. Alternatively you could use `serde_json::Value`, then it would be able to safely save/load any arbitrary JSON values. However, you may need to manually delete the `options.json` file when you change the contents of `Options` since it may panic upon failing to parse the previous version.

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Options {
    window_position: (u32, u32),
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut options = match load_previous_data::<Options>().unwrap() {
        Some(v) => v,
        // Options has not been created yet, so create some default config
        None => Options {
            window_size: (500, 500),
        },
    };

    // Run program

    // Save options before exiting
    save_data_for_next(&options).unwrap();
}
```